# What is the right way to test a SQLAlchemy dialect?

Tags: python, sql, testing, sqlalchemy

I implement my own SQLAlchemy dialect for a RDBMS.

What is the best way to test the dialect, I've implemented?
Are there any automated test suites, that could help me?

What is the best way to make sure, that my implementation is correct
and supports all necessary features?

Comment: I would say that looking at the test coverage of existing dialects would be a way to start. See [`sqlalchemy/test/dialects`](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/tree/master/test/dialect) code for this.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the README included with the SQLAlchemy distribution regarding exactly how this is done as of version 0.8 of SQLAlchemy:

https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/README.dialects.rst